# Fixing wrong-type-argument to looking-at in Emacs 25 js-mode on large files

Tags: debugging, javascript, js2-mode

When using js-mode (or js2-mode) on Emacs 25.1 (in Debian 9) to edit some large files, any attempt to insert text after some "random" point in the file fails with an elisp stack trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  looking-at(nil)
  c-state-semi-safe-place(269817)
  c-literal-limits(nil nil t)
  c-context-line-break()
  funcall-interactively(c-context-line-break)
  call-interactively(c-context-line-break nil nil)
  command-execute(c-context-line-break)
```

Why and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that my personal config (and those of the people I tested this with) manually bound `C-m` to `c-context-line-break` in `js-mode`.  So the right answer is to not do this (and leave it as `newline-and-indent`.)  Silly me.

**Original "workaround":**

The `looking-at(nil)` gave a pretty good hint that this was a `cc-mode` regex left unset by `js-mode` and `js2-mode`.  An Edebug session quickly showed that the culprit was `c-block-comment-start-regexp`.

So, to fix it, I just defined that variable in a hook in `~/.emacs`.  For example, for `js-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda () (setq c-block-comment-start-regexp "/\\*")))
```

Comment: Arguably, the bug is that js-mode uses `c-context-line-break` even tho it's not a "cc-mode".

Comment: This might be worth reporting to maintainers of `js-mode`.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: Good point.  I've sent the maintainer a note.

Comment: Ha, and guess what.  It turns out that it's _my_ configuration (and those of everyone else I had try this out, by chance) that binds C-m to c-context-line-break!  Oops.  Well, I guess I'll fix this the right way by not doing that.